# How to make " xx km " from Location, geo/google api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Ok I have a restaurant list. All the restaurants have a adresses, and I would like to do so you can write a location in a input field, and then it will show the restaurant list with the closest first and then descending.. example:

Searching for: Valby (city in Denmark)

```
Restaurant Ankrara - 2 km from Valby
Restaurant JuicyFood - 3 km from Valby
Restaurant FoodJuicy - 5 km from Valby
Restaurant Blabla - 22 km from Valby
```

After research and question here on SO, I found out I need to use geocoding and google maps api.

Okay, so I got to the step where I have converted what you entered (the city Valby in above example), into geocode (lat/lng coordinates).

And then i have the adresses in the coordinates to.

How can i count the kilometers between the City and the restaurant address in coordinates?

For the example, here is the cords of the city "Valby":

```
55.662133, 12.508028
```

And here is 3 restaurants addresses cords:

```
55.667029, 12.527715
55.6939821, 12.4934945
55.6696885, 12.3755492
```

(And how can i show them with closest/nearest first and then descending <- not required for accepted answer, I eventually make a new question for this)

Comment: To clarify, do you need the distance following the roads, or just as a straight line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the distances:

```
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(55.662133, 12.508028);

var r1 = {name: "rest1", lat: 55.667029, lng: 12.527715, dist: 0};
var r2 = {name: "rest2", lat: 55.6939821, lng: 12.4934945, dist: 0};
var r3 = {name: "rest3", lat: 55.6696885, lng: 12.3755492, dist: 0};

var r = [r3, r2, r1];
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; ++i) {
    var p = new google.maps.LatLng(r[i].lat, r[i].lng);
    var d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pos, p);
    r[i].dist = d;
}
```

and then sort them:

```
r.sort(function(r1, r2) {return r1.dist - r2.dist;});
```

For details see the [running source code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4veJK/).

Comment: computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2): p1 and p2 must be LatLng. You can check my program.

Comment: Ok it starts to works but one issue. When i do this: computeRestaurants(55.662133, 12.508028) and then it looks like function computeRestaurants(pos){ var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(pos); } i get NaN. I found out its because its adding brackets, () So it does new google.maps.LatLng(((55.662133, 12.508028)); which does not work and gives NaN. How can i fix this so it can take positions outfrom the function?

Comment: OPTION 1: define `function compRest(pos) {..use directly pos..}` and call it as `compRest(new google.maps.LatLng(55.6, 12.5));`. OPTION 2: define `function compRest(lat,lng) {var pos=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng); ...}`. Call it as `compRest(55.6, 12.5);`

Comment: Try `computeRestaurants(point)` because `point` is already LatLng. I would recommend you to switch to the latest Google Maps v3.

Comment: Still NaN :(. I thought this was the latest. How can i switch to the latest, and then maybe this solution will not work anymore?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866060/write-a-location-and-get-the-geocords-not-working-properly-js

Comment: Please help me out. And i cant use your OPTION 2 since `point` comes in one variable (11.1, 12.2) please i would love any help

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the distances on your server. See article [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html)