# Write a location and get the geocords, not working properly? JS

Tags: google-maps, geocode, google-geocoder

Link removed

This is my site. Im working on so you can enter a location on the search input field, and then see theres xx km from a restaurant.

Now i got almost everything working. If you see the source code you can see how it works. It showAddress(what you searched). And then show addresses makes it into lat/lng cords, and pass it to computeRestaurants() which computes the distances between the location you entered and the restaurants.

Somehow, when I run:

```
computeRestaurants(new google.maps.LatLng(55.662133, 12.508028));
```

outside the functions, it works and gives correct values.

But when i do:

```
showAddress('Valby'); // (like in the source code)
```

You can see that it returns NaN. And inside showAddress() it executes the same command as the one i wrote above computeRestaurants( the point )

So why will it not work properly?

`point` in showAddress is: `(55.662133, 12.508028)` so it is already converted to LatLng cords and therefore no need to `new google.maps.latlng(...`

My only bet right now is the brackets () ??

Comment: Don't know if you fixed it already, but the problem is here: `function computeRestaurants(lat, lng)` expects 2 params, but you give one: `computeRestaurants(point);`.

Comment: @confused-demon I was just still trying to figure out a way that would work thats why i tred adding to params for the computeRestaurants(), but its back to only one, `pos` now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your showAddress by this:

```
var geocoder;
function showAddress(address)
{
  if (typeof(geocoder) == 'undefined') geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      computeRestaurants(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

You are using mixup of v2 and v3 apis, and that is the problem.